# Pseudorandom generator designs

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

When designing pseudorandom generators what should one consider? Here is an example pseudorandom generator $F^t : \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{4n}$. I have no idea what it means, so what does it kindly mean? It is one proposal written in a book for the truly random compression function $t : \{0,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$

Like how would I design one for truly random compression function such as $t : \{0,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$?

Answer (score 2):

It just defines a function that expands the input size with the output size four times, where the output depends on configuration value $t$ as well. The hash function compresses the input to an output that is half the size (which is not common, usually a hash function outputs a constant size hash).

Here ^ is *not* a power function. It simply shows how many elements there are sequentially taken from the input set $\{0, 1\}$ - properly formatted it reads $\{0, 1\}^{4 \cdot n}$. So the $x$ in $\{0, 1\}^x$ simply defines an input or output consisting of $x$ bits - with value $0$ or $1$ of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Sir! So basically, what you are saying is that with a PRG, it takes a fixed size `n` and then outputs 4 times `n`? Also, how would I design a PRG for the random compression function listed in my question?

Comment: Not a fixed size, no. If the size were fixed, even for a single call, then you would add $n$ to the configuration parameters. It simply expands *any* input to two times the size, the way I read it (context is important though, maybe $n$ is set to a value elsewhere). I don't think you should use a PRG such as this to create a hash function - was that actually a question?

Comment: I'm trying to come up with a PRG based on the random compression function `t : {0,1}^2n -> {0,1}^n`. The thing is, I didn't know anything about PRGs but just to get things started a PRG always start like F^t : {0,1}^n? The last bit `-> {0,1}^xn` where `x` is a number is how it ends right? I just wanna design a PRG for the random compression function. Just out of interest, why is the mentioned random compression function not a block cipher either?

Comment: You seem to make two different requests now, creating a PRG based on a compression function and the other way around. A block cipher is a PRP, which is *always* $F_k: \{0, 1\}^n \to \{0, 1\}^n$ because there has to be a $F^{-1}_k$: encryption *and* decryption.

Comment: Sorry sir for confusion. So basically, you have mentioned a interesting fact about a block cipher being a PRP (I'm learning something new today! You made my day honestly!!) My question is why the truly random compression function Fk : {0,1} ^ 2n -> {0,1} ^ n isn't a block cipher?? I am so sorry if I sound really stupid (I am very stupid at crypto, maths in general) and so sorry for writing it like a noob. BTW what is a PRP?? So sorry I am new to crypto and IT advance as a whole

Comment: You have an input larger than the output. So encryption has to map some values to two or more values. However, during decryption, how are you going to chose between the possible input values during encryption? A block cipher implements a *keyed* 1 : 1 map where the input and output values are identical (a permutation, or reordering of the input values, in other words), where the mapping for all keys is pseudo-random. You cannot have a 1 : 1 map if the input and output sizes differ.

Comment: Thanks for the explaination good Sir!!! The thing is, I read in some sources that truly random compression function `{0,1}^2n -> {0,1}^n` can be block cipher because it maps :S :S? Sorry, if you can clear this for me , mean a lot to me. Also so sorry again what is PRP?

Comment: You have really really been of good help Sir! Thanks so much :) I just wanna learn more about crypto and just how to kindly design a PRG for a compression function such as the ones I have mentioned. It has meant a lot to me for you to explain it to me as I am self-learning everything as I work full-time and not able to go college etc...

Comment: [Here](http://www.katjaas.nl/bitreversal/bits.jpg) is a permutation on 3 bits input. It is obviously not pseudo random as it simply reverses the bits. Imagine a key that chooses a specific, random looking order of output for all the input. That's a pseudo random permutation and thus a block cipher. Again: a compression function cannot be a PRP. You need $2^n$ output values for each key.

Comment: Thanks for explaining it Sir! I get it now thanks to you. Basically, it has to be a 1:1 mapping and if there are collisions, i.e. two inputs give the same output then it isn't a block cipher as a block cipher is supposed to be random!! THANKS :D. With regards to the PRG, I came up with `Gt: {0,1} -> {0,1} (n/2) * 2` but I think it is wrong for the random compression function I defined