# PRG Theory Design

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

PRG theory design is something of interest to me at the moment in the security of cryptography.

I am interested in learning how to come with PRGs for random functions such as $\{0,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ and $\{0,1\}^{3n} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$

One PRG that I came up with for the random compression function $\{0,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ is $\{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\}^{2n+1}$. My understanding of my own PRG is that it takes an input of $n$ and then outputs $2\times$ the input $+1$. The thing is, I am not sure if this would be suitable for the book example random compression function $f: \{0,1\}^{2n} \rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$. I think I am making a mistake somewhere.

I am sure someone can help pick up the error

Comment: You keep talking about compression functions. However a PRG is expanding by definition. There must be some very basic misconception going on here.

Comment: Other similar recent question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/64508/pseudorandom-generator-designs

Answer (score 2):

> One PRG that I came up with for the random compression function $\{0,1\}^{2n}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ is $\{0,1\}^n→\{0,1\}^{2n+1}$. My understanding of my own PRG is that it takes an input of $n$ and then outputs $2×$ the input $+1$.

That is not what this notation means.

$\{0, 1\}^{2n}$ means a block of $2n$ bits.

$\{0, 1\}^n$ means a block of $n$ bits.

$\{0,1\}^{2n}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ means that a block of $2n$ bits is mapped to a block of $n$ bits.

So a statement such as "$\{0,1\}^{2n}\rightarrow \{0,1\}^n$ is $\{0,1\}^n→\{0,1\}^{2n+1}$" makes no sense. It says: "a block of $2n$ bits is mapped to a block of $n$ bits, which is a block of $n$ bits mapped to a block of $2n+1$ bits", which is clearly a contradiction.

This notation is not used to indicate what the function actually does, it says what the range of inputs and the range of outputs are. So it does not indicate that it takes an input of $n$ and outputs $2 * (n + 1)$.